# Java simple drawing program using bookClasses SimpleTurtle

Tags: java, oop, mouseevent, mouselistener, turtle-graphics

For my online Java class I've been trying to get a simple drawing program to work. I am using [bookClasses](http://home.cc.gatech.edu/TeaParty/47) (to run the program you need this library) to make a world object with a turtle in it. To draw, I've been using a mouselistener. My problem is that I have two windows: one that I draw on, the other that the lines show up on. I would like to draw on the same window the lines are creates on. [Here](http://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/doc/SimpleTurtle.html) is the documentation for the turtle I am using. (I'm using just Turtle here which inherits from SimpleTurtle). Anyway, here's my code:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
   World worldObj = new World();
   Turtle turtle = new Turtle(1000, 1000, worldObj);

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int xPressed = e.getX();
        int yPressed = e.getY();
        System.out.printf("Mouse Clicked at: %d, %d%n", xPressed, yPressed);
        turtle.hide();
        turtle.penUp();
        turtle.moveTo(xPressed, yPressed);
   }
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
       int xReleased = e.getX();
       int yReleased = e.getY();
       System.out.printf("Mouse Released at: %d, %d%n", xReleased, yReleased);
       turtle.show();
       turtle.penDown();
       turtle.moveTo(xReleased, yReleased);
       turtle.hide();
   }
}

public class WorldTest2 {   
   public WorldTest2() {
       World worldObj = new World();
       worldObj.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       WorldTest2 test = new WorldTest2();
   }   
}
```

I realize why it doesn't work (I'm creating the turtle on one world, but the mouse listener on another), but I don't know how I can fix it. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I thought I had tried everything, but I guess I was wrong! While messing around with it I figured out a solution.

I just changed

```
   public WorldTest2() {
   World worldObj = new World();
   worldObj.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
   }
```

to

```
   public WorldTest2() {
   MyMouseAdapter draw = new MyMouseAdapter();
   draw.worldObj.addMouseListener(draw);
   }
```

and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

In your WorldTest 2 class add a `getter()` method

```
public class WorldTest2{
      World worldObj;
      public World(){
           worldObj = new World();
       }
       public World getWorld(){ //Now call this in MyMouseAdapter Class 
           return worldObj;         // instead of creating new Object of World
       }
 }
```

In `MyMouseAdapter` class

```
class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
   World worldObj = new WorldTest2().getWorld();
}
```